# Apache doesn't work if importing python packages on Windows

Tags: python, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I set up an apache server on Windows with mod_wsgi, python 3.7.
I use anaconda distribution.

If I `call mod_wsgi-express module-config`

I get this :
 `LoadFile "c:/programdata/anaconda3/envs/processing/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/programdata/anaconda3/envs/processing/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/programdata/anaconda3/envs/processing/"`
So I did put it in httpd.conf. then in httpd-vhosts.conf i have this: `<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  localhost
        WSGIScriptAlias / C:\Source\PreProcessAPI\web.wsgi
        DocumentRoot "C:\Source\PreProcessAPI"
        <Directory "C:\Source\PreProcessAPI">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

my web.wsgi looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Source/PreProcessAPI/")  

from t import app as application
```

and my flask app looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask,request





#%%init
app = Flask(__name__)


#%%Root Get
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return "hello"

#%%Main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

and it works like this, just fine. but if I import anything else ie import pandas.
then the whole server just looks like idle-out. It just keeps loading the page, and doesn't put anything to the log files.
If i just run my flask app after activating the processing env then it works with the packages as well.

There is very few documentations for windows as I see. Hope someone can help.

update:
 if I install mod_wsgi to the base env and run it with that module included to the httpd.conf then I get import errors but from inside of the modules. i.e. it start to import numpy and it has import error with some random submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok It looks like if I just add

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

It will work because it will force the app to use the given interpreter.
I thought this setting only works on linux.. But luckily it works also on windows!